# Saving shell command output in python script to text file

Tags: terminal, python

I manage to call and use a terminal command in my python script, in which it is working.

But currently I am trying to save the 'output' result from this command into a text file but I am getting errors.

This is my initial code in which it is doing correctly:

```
import os
os.system("someCmds --proj ARCH --all")
```

The code that I used when I tried to save the outputs into a text file:

```
import os
import sys
sys.stdout=open("output.txt","w")
command = os.system("someCmds --proj ARCH --all")
print command
sys.stdout.close()
```

However I got the following error - `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`

I did close the file as I found this online. So where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The Python programming part of this is more appropriate for stackoverflow.com.  However, there's a Unix-oriented component as well.

Every process has three well-known *file descriptors*.  While they have names—stdin, stdout, and stderr—they are actually known by their file *numbers*, which are 0, 1, and 2 respectively.  To run a program and capture its stdout—its file-number-1 output—you must connect *that process's* file-descriptor-1 to a file or pipe.

In the command-line shells, there is syntax for this:

```
prog > file
```

runs program `prog`, in a process whose stdout is connected to an open *file descriptor* that has been moved into descriptor-slot-1.  Actually making all that happen at the system-call level is complicated:

1. Open the file.  This results in a open file descriptor, whose number is probably higher than 2 since zero-through-two are your own stdin, stdout, and stderr.
2. Use the `fork` system call or one of its variants: this makes a clone of yourself.
3. In the clone (but not in the original), *move* the file descriptor from wherever it is now, to file descriptor 1.  Then close the original higher-numbered descriptor (and any others that you have open that you do not wish to pass on).
4. Use one of the the `exec` family of calls to terminate yourself (the clone) but in the process, replace everything with the program `prog`.  This maintains all your open file descriptors, including the one pointing to the file or pipe you moved in step 3.  Once the `exec` succeeds, you no longer exist and cannot do anything.  (If the `exec` *fails*, report the failure and exit.)
5. Back in the original (*parent*) process, wait for the clone-child to exec and then finish, or to fail, or whatever happens.

Python being what it is, this multi-step sequence is all wrapped up for you, with fancy error checking, in the `subprocess` module.  Instead of using `os.system`, you can use `subprocess.Popen`.  It's designed to work with pipes—which are actually more difficult than files—so if you really want to redirect to a *file*, rather than simply reading the program's output through a pipe, you will want to open the file first, *then* invoke `subprocess.Popen`.

In any case, altering your Python process's `sys.stdout` is not helpful, as `sys.stdout` is a Python data structure quite independent of the underlying file descriptor system.  By `open`ing a Python stream, you do obtain a file descriptor (as well as a Python data structure), but it is not file-descriptor-number-1.  The underlying file descriptor number, whatever it is, has to be *moved* to the slot-1 position *after* the `fork` call, in the clone.  Even if you use `subprocess.Popen`, the only descriptor Python will move, post-fork, is the one you pass as the `stdout=` argument.

(Subprocess's `Popen` accepts any of these:

- a Python stream: Python uses `stream.fileno()` to get the descriptor number, or
- an integer: Python assumes that this represents an open file descriptor that should be moved to fd 0, 1, or 2 depending on whether this is an argument to `stdin=`, `stdout=`, or `stderr=`, or
- the special values `subprocess.PIPE` or, for `stderr=`, `subprocess.STDOUT`: these tell it that Python should create a pipe, or re-use the previously-created stdout pipe for the special `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` case.

The library is pretty fancy and knows how to report, with a Python traceback, a failure to `exec`, or various other failures that occur in the child.  It does this using another auxiliary pipe with close-on-exec.  EOF on this pipe means the exec succeeded; otherwise the data arriving on this extra pipe include the failure, converted to a byte stream using the `pickle` module.)